How do I enforce disabling of C++ exceptions?
I'm using C++ for a low-level firmware project for a microcontroller. Everything was fine for a while, with code size kept very small, until I introduced this line of code:
    uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(exti_set_mask);
    auto &gpio_irq_info = irq_callback_table[index];

The issue here is that irq_callback_table is an std::array<> of size 16. exti_set_mask is a uint16_t that is probably being promoted to a uint32_t (32-bit CPU architecture), so the compiler cannot be sure that the result of __builtin_ctz() returns something smaller than 16. With the potential of an out-of-bounds access, the program code size blows up because of all the code added to support throwing of an exception.
Masking the result before using it as an index gets rid of all of that exception code:
uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(exti_set_mask) & 0xf;
auto &gpio_irq_info = irq_callback_table[index];

Which brings the program code size back down to about 4 kB v.s. 90 kB!
I have these flags set via meson:
# Specify global compiler flags.
add_project_arguments(
    # Free standing environment (no OS, or stdlib)
    '-ffreestanding', '-nostdlib', '-specs=nosys.specs',
    # Enable linker garbage collection
    '-ffunction-sections', '-fdata-sections',
    # No dynamic memory allocation
    '-fno-builtin-malloc', '-fno-builtin-calloc',
    '-fno-builtin-realloc', '-fno-builtin-free',
    # Debug optimization
    '-Og',
    language: ['cpp', 'c']
)
add_project_arguments(
    '-std=c++20',
    '-fno-exceptions',
    '-fno-rtti',
    language: ['cpp']
)

But the -fno-exceptions flag does not seem to be enough to prevent emitting of exception code. Ideally, I would want any potential emission of exceptions (or malloc, etc) to show up as a warning or error instead. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?

EDIT:
For those that want to compare the .elf file objdump output, here's the fully linked .elf with the masked index: https://pastebin.com/hSJgF3PW
And the .elf with the non-masked index:

https://pastebin.com/p9yDxdjx pt1
https://pastebin.com/NU5nV0tr pt2
https://pastebin.com/9CX1EtH0 pt3
https://pastebin.com/evvnmCCa pt4

The function where the two deviate:
Non-masked index:
08000d1c <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)>:
void CommonISRHandler([[maybe_unused]] uint16_t exti_set_mask) {
 8000d1c:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 8000d1e:   0005        movs    r5, r0
  while (exti_set_mask) {
 8000d20:   e011        b.n 8000d46 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x2a>
      // Element access.
      [[__nodiscard__]]
      _GLIBCXX17_CONSTEXPR reference
      operator[](size_type __n) noexcept
      {
    __glibcxx_requires_subscript(__n);
 8000d22:   4b18        ldr r3, [pc, #96]   @ (8000d84 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x68>)
 8000d24:   4a18        ldr r2, [pc, #96]   @ (8000d88 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x6c>)
 8000d26:   4819        ldr r0, [pc, #100]  @ (8000d8c <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x70>)
 8000d28:   21ca        movs    r1, #202    @ 0xca
 8000d2a:   f000 f97d   bl  8001028 <std::__glibcxx_assert_fail(char const*, int, char const*, char const*)>
    EXTI->RPR1 &= (1 << index);
 8000d2e:   4a18        ldr r2, [pc, #96]   @ (8000d90 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x74>)
 8000d30:   68d1        ldr r1, [r2, #12]
 8000d32:   2301        movs    r3, #1
 8000d34:   40a3        lsls    r3, r4
 8000d36:   4019        ands    r1, r3
 8000d38:   60d1        str r1, [r2, #12]
    EXTI->FPR1 &= (1 << index);
 8000d3a:   6911        ldr r1, [r2, #16]
 8000d3c:   4019        ands    r1, r3
 8000d3e:   6111        str r1, [r2, #16]
    exti_set_mask &= ~(1 << index);
 8000d40:   43db        mvns    r3, r3
 8000d42:   b21b        sxth    r3, r3
 8000d44:   401d        ands    r5, r3
  while (exti_set_mask) {
 8000d46:   2d00        cmp r5, #0
 8000d48:   d01a        beq.n   8000d80 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x64>
    uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(exti_set_mask);
 8000d4a:   0028        movs    r0, r5
 8000d4c:   f7ff fa40   bl  80001d0 <__ctzsi2>
    auto &gpio_irq_info = irq_callback_table[index];
 8000d50:   24ff        movs    r4, #255    @ 0xff
 8000d52:   4004        ands    r4, r0
 8000d54:   2c0f        cmp r4, #15
 8000d56:   d8e4        bhi.n   8000d22 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x6>
    return stub_ptr != nullptr;
 8000d58:   4b0e        ldr r3, [pc, #56]   @ (8000d94 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x78>)
 8000d5a:   0062        lsls    r2, r4, #1
 8000d5c:   1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
 8000d5e:   0092        lsls    r2, r2, #2
 8000d60:   189b        adds    r3, r3, r2
 8000d62:   689b        ldr r3, [r3, #8]
    if (gpio_irq_info.callback.IsValid()) {
 8000d64:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
 8000d66:   d0e2        beq.n   8000d2e <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x12>
      gpio_irq_info.callback(gpio_irq_info.pin);
 8000d68:   4a0a        ldr r2, [pc, #40]   @ (8000d94 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x78>)
 8000d6a:   0060        lsls    r0, r4, #1
 8000d6c:   1901        adds    r1, r0, r4
 8000d6e:   0089        lsls    r1, r1, #2
 8000d70:   5c89        ldrb    r1, [r1, r2]
 8000d72:   1900        adds    r0, r0, r4
 8000d74:   0080        lsls    r0, r0, #2
 8000d76:   1880        adds    r0, r0, r2
 8000d78:   3004        adds    r0, #4
 8000d7a:   f7ff ffbb   bl  8000cf4 <rtlib::Delegate<void (mcu::stm32g070::Gpio::GpioId)>::operator()(mcu::stm32g070::Gpio::GpioId) const>
 8000d7e:   e7d6        b.n 8000d2e <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x12>
}
 8000d80:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
 8000d82:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
 8000d84:   08013ccc    .word   0x08013ccc
 8000d88:   08013ce0    .word   0x08013ce0
 8000d8c:   08013dc4    .word   0x08013dc4
 8000d90:   40021800    .word   0x40021800
 8000d94:   20000734    .word   0x20000734

Masked index:
08000710 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)>:
void CommonISRHandler([[maybe_unused]] uint16_t exti_set_mask) {
 8000710:   b570        push    {r4, r5, r6, lr}
 8000712:   0005        movs    r5, r0
  while (exti_set_mask) {
 8000714:   e00b        b.n 800072e <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x1e>
    EXTI->RPR1 &= (1 << index);
 8000716:   4a14        ldr r2, [pc, #80]   @ (8000768 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x58>)
 8000718:   68d1        ldr r1, [r2, #12]
 800071a:   2301        movs    r3, #1
 800071c:   40a3        lsls    r3, r4
 800071e:   4019        ands    r1, r3
 8000720:   60d1        str r1, [r2, #12]
    EXTI->FPR1 &= (1 << index);
 8000722:   6911        ldr r1, [r2, #16]
 8000724:   4019        ands    r1, r3
 8000726:   6111        str r1, [r2, #16]
    exti_set_mask &= ~(1 << index);
 8000728:   43db        mvns    r3, r3
 800072a:   b21b        sxth    r3, r3
 800072c:   401d        ands    r5, r3
  while (exti_set_mask) {
 800072e:   2d00        cmp r5, #0
 8000730:   d018        beq.n   8000764 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x54>
    uint8_t index = __builtin_ctz(exti_set_mask) & 0xf;
 8000732:   0028        movs    r0, r5
 8000734:   f7ff fcc0   bl  80000b8 <__ctzsi2>
 8000738:   240f        movs    r4, #15
 800073a:   4004        ands    r4, r0
    return stub_ptr != nullptr;
 800073c:   4b0b        ldr r3, [pc, #44]   @ (800076c <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x5c>)
 800073e:   0062        lsls    r2, r4, #1
 8000740:   1912        adds    r2, r2, r4
 8000742:   0092        lsls    r2, r2, #2
 8000744:   189b        adds    r3, r3, r2
 8000746:   689b        ldr r3, [r3, #8]
    if (gpio_irq_info.callback.IsValid()) {
 8000748:   2b00        cmp r3, #0
 800074a:   d0e4        beq.n   8000716 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x6>
      gpio_irq_info.callback(gpio_irq_info.pin);
 800074c:   4a07        ldr r2, [pc, #28]   @ (800076c <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x5c>)
 800074e:   0060        lsls    r0, r4, #1
 8000750:   1901        adds    r1, r0, r4
 8000752:   0089        lsls    r1, r1, #2
 8000754:   5c89        ldrb    r1, [r1, r2]
 8000756:   1900        adds    r0, r0, r4
 8000758:   0080        lsls    r0, r0, #2
 800075a:   1880        adds    r0, r0, r2
 800075c:   3004        adds    r0, #4
 800075e:   f7ff ffc3   bl  80006e8 <rtlib::Delegate<void (mcu::stm32g070::Gpio::GpioId)>::operator()(mcu::stm32g070::Gpio::GpioId) const>
 8000762:   e7d8        b.n 8000716 <(anonymous namespace)::CommonISRHandler(unsigned short)+0x6>
}
 8000764:   bd70        pop {r4, r5, r6, pc}
 8000766:   46c0        nop         @ (mov r8, r8)
 8000768:   40021800    .word   0x40021800
 800076c:   2000005c    .word   0x2000005c

EDIT #2, Some good comments so far, thank you. My reason for believing that exceptions are being pulled in is because of the presence of many functions in the non-masked objdump that are not present in the masked objdump output (grep -i exception, grep -i throw):
08000438 <_Unwind_RaiseException>:
 800045e:       f009 f831       bl      80094c4 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException>
 8001764:       f007 fb0e       bl      8008d84 <__cxa_current_exception_type>
080089d8 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)>:
 80089e0:       d000            beq.n   80089e4 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xc>
 80089e8:       d1fb            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 80089ee:       d1f8            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 80089f4:       d1f5            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 80089fa:       d1f2            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 8008a00:       d1ef            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 8008a06:       d1ec            bne.n   80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 8008a12:       e7e6            b.n     80089e2 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)+0xa>
 8008a20:       f7ff ffda       bl      80089d8 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)>
 8008a44:       f7ff ffc8       bl      80089d8 <__cxxabiv1::__is_gxx_exception_class(char*)>
 8008b02:       f000 fad3       bl      80090ac <__cxa_allocate_exception>
 8008bc0:       f000 fce6       bl      8009590 <_Unwind_DeleteException>
 8008c2c:       f000 fcb0       bl      8009590 <_Unwind_DeleteException>
08008c34 <std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()>:
08008c38 <transaction clone for std::bad_exception::what() const>:
 8008c38:       4800            ldr     r0, [pc, #0]    @ (8008c3c <transaction clone for std::bad_exception::what() const+0x4>)
08008c40 <std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()>:
08008c60 <__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Control_Block*)>:
 8008c64:       d812            bhi.n   8008c8c <__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Control_Block*)+0x2c>
 8008c72:       d000            beq.n   8008c76 <__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Control_Block*)+0x16>
 8008c7e:       d001            beq.n   8008c84 <__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Control_Block*)+0x24>
 8008c86:       f000 fa27       bl      80090d8 <__cxa_free_exception>
 8008c8a:       e7f3            b.n     8008c74 <__gxx_exception_cleanup(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Control_Block*)+0x14>
08008c94 <__cxa_init_primary_exception>:
 8008cd0:       4b02            ldr     r3, [pc, #8]    @ (8008cdc <__cxa_init_primary_exception+0x48>)
 8008cf8:       f7ff ffcc       bl      8008c94 <__cxa_init_primary_exception>
 8008d06:       f7f7 fb97       bl      8000438 <_Unwind_RaiseException>
08008d84 <__cxa_current_exception_type>:
 8008d8e:       d004            beq.n   8008d9a <__cxa_current_exception_type+0x16>
 8008d96:       d001            beq.n   8008d9c <__cxa_current_exception_type+0x18>
 8008da0:       e7fa            b.n     8008d98 <__cxa_current_exception_type+0x14>
080090ac <__cxa_allocate_exception>:
 80090b8:       d007            beq.n   80090ca <__cxa_allocate_exception+0x1e>
 80090d2:       d1f2            bne.n   80090ba <__cxa_allocate_exception+0xe>
080090d8 <__cxa_free_exception>:
 80090d8:       4b07            ldr     r3, [pc, #28]   @ (80090f8 <__cxa_free_exception+0x20>)
 80090e6:       d201            bcs.n   80090ec <__cxa_free_exception+0x14>
 80090ea:       d302            bcc.n   80090f2 <__cxa_free_exception+0x1a>
 80090f6:       e7fb            b.n     80090f0 <__cxa_free_exception+0x18>
080094c4 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException>:
 80094e0:       e006            b.n     80094f0 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+0x2c>
 80094ee:       d108            bne.n   8009502 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+0x3e>
 80094fa:       d0f2            beq.n   80094e2 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+0x1e>
 800950a:       d1f7            bne.n   80094fc <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException+0x38>
 8009584:       f7ff ff9e       bl      80094c4 <__gnu_Unwind_RaiseException>
08009590 <_Unwind_DeleteException>:
 8009598:       d001            beq.n   800959e <_Unwind_DeleteException+0xe>

08000498 <_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow>:
 80004be:       f009 f857       bl      8009570 <__gnu_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow>
 80017c6:       f007 faa5       bl      8008d14 <__cxa_rethrow>
 8008ad0:       f000 f920       bl      8008d14 <__cxa_rethrow>
 8008b0e:       f000 f8e7       bl      8008ce0 <__cxa_throw>
08008ce0 <__cxa_throw>:
08008d14 <__cxa_rethrow>:
 8008d24:       d00c            beq.n   8008d40 <__cxa_rethrow+0x2c>
 8008d2c:       d00a            beq.n   8008d44 <__cxa_rethrow+0x30>
 8008d36:       f7f7 fbaf       bl      8000498 <_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow>
 8008d4a:       d1f0            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d52:       d1ec            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d5a:       d1e8            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d62:       d1e4            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d6a:       d1e0            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d72:       d1dc            bne.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d7a:       d8d8            bhi.n   8008d2e <__cxa_rethrow+0x1a>
 8008d82:       e7d6            b.n     8008d32 <__cxa_rethrow+0x1e>
08009570 <__gnu_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow>:
 8009576:       d005            beq.n   8009584 <__gnu_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow+0x14>
 8009588:       e7fb            b.n     8009582 <__gnu_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow+0x12>


Even if it's not perfect, did you try to directly use data , ie something like irq_callback_table.data()[index] ?

How do you know that this is related to exceptions? What prof do you have?

My guess the issue you have is that you are not compiling with optimizations turned on.  Most libraries introduce debugging coded into functions that normally would not in debug mode and then remove those checks in optimized/release builds.  This helps both the programmer debug the code and also allow for fast production code.

@Someprogrammerdude, I examined the produced object files with objdump and diffed between the code which masked and didn't mask. The difference was all code related to exceptions.

@NathanOliver, Ok, I'll look into that. But even so, I would want my debug builds to be free of exception code. They simply cannot be that large - the MCU I'm working with has 128 kB of program code space, so going from 4 kB to 90 kB with the inclusion of exceptions is not sustainable for continuing to develop and add new features.

@edrezen, accessing using the raw pointer (and without masking the index) successfully prevents emission of exception related code, but does that mean I simply should not use std::array<> then and just opt for raw C-arrays for embedded code?

Then it could well be an optimization issue, that you build with a debug-library that contains exceptions for the [] operator. The release build (also add the NDEBUG macro when building) should not have exceptions for that operator. And of course build with -O3 for release.

Using std::array::operator[] should not be an issue since this operator doesn't involve any exception stuff (on the other hand std::array::at does use exception). The weird part is that, since you use -fno-exceptions, you should have a compilation error if some of your code (directly or indirectly) throws an exception or has some try/catch block.

@edrezen
@Someprogrammerdude
When I get time later, I'll reproduce the objdump diff and paste some of what I see in a pastebin. Just to make sure I'm not misinterpreting the difference to be exception related.

What exception is (or would be) thrown?

Just saying; lots of C++ stuff won't work properly / will work in surprising ways, if you disable exceptions.

@edrezen Disabling exceptions don't turn them in to compiler errors in all cases. They may just turn into undefined or implementation defined behaviour.

Maybe there is a bug or misconfiguration in the build system. Are you sure that your compile flags set in meson actually end up in the compiler command? Try changing some other flags and see if they affect the build or not. For example, try -std=c++11 instead of -std=c++20.

So basically you say, if I get an invalid value back from a function and I do not check that value use that invalid value as an index into an array then my code blows up. Ofcourse it does because you have UB (access an array out of bound). This has nothing to do with exceptions, but with your lack of checking the value of the index before using it.  You should check if ( index  < irq_callback_table.size() ) { auto &gpio_irq_info = irq_callback_table[index]; .... }. And/or figure out why you can even get an invalid value.  Also using calls starting with __ is very very questionable

@PepijnKramer, What I mean to say is the code size blows up. Yes I understand it's potentially undefined behavior, but in practice, it's impossible if starting with a uint16_t.  That's not the issue here.

@edrezen
@Someprogrammerdude I've edited the question to provide the objdump of the two fully linked .elf files

Me bad, I missed the &0xF (which might work if you know your mask input is ok)

This doesn't look like it has anything to do with exceptions. The non-masked code references __glibcxx_assert_fail. Obviously, the implementation of array::operator[] contains an assertion that the index is in range. But since you do not use -DNDEBUG to compile the code, the assertion remains in the code instead of being omitted.

uint16_t that is probably being promoted to a uint32_t (32-bit CPU architecture)  On 32-bit architecture, a uint16_t will get promoted to an int (which will be an int32_t).

If your platform supports a compiler option like hardening, you need turn it off. That option injects unwanted assertions in debug builds.

try -U_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS or -fno-hardened

@j6t Why did all these symbols get pulled in then? <_Unwind_RaiseException>:, 08000428 <__gnu_Unwind_Restore_WMMXD>: 0800042c <__gnu_Unwind_Save_WMMXD>: 08000430 <__gnu_Unwind_Restore_WMMXC>: 08000434 <__gnu_Unwind_Save_WMMXC>:

@j6t Updated the question to include the exception symbols. You can see them yourself in the pastebin links as well.

@Red.Wave -U_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS worked in bringing the code size back down! -fno-hardened didn't exist as a flag (arm-none-eabi-gcc 13.3.1). So what exactly is going on with -U_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS? Feel free to leave an answer too. Please consider the updates that I edited in the question too.

Much easier than using Standard library with exceptions disabled is to use an implementation designed with no-exceptions as an option. For embedded projects you may want to check https://www.etlcpp.com/

In recent years, safety has become a nuance in SW development world. As a result, compiler and library designers have shifted toward hardening programs against usual sources of UB. As part of their attemps recent compilers have hardening flags enabled by default in debug builds. Hardening flags eventually affect the behavior of indexing operators for std::array, std::vector and contagious ranges in general. As a result, index operator(operator[]) for the afformentioned classes practically become equivalent to at method.
In order to disable the adverse effects of hardening on performance, the easiest solution is to compile in release mode(force define _NDRBUG via compiler flags). But this totally disables runtime debuggers and traps. The better choice is to keep the debug mode, but dissable the harmful hardening options.

_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS is a macro that enables selective assertions in GNU libraries and related frameworks. As part of code hardening, developers can opt to define it via the D switch(as -D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS). But as mentioned before, that's the default in debug builds. Thus, in case necessary definition of that macro can be suppressed via the U compiler switch(-U_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS). Tracing the definitions in IDE, we can see that _GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS macro conditionally controls bounds checks in gnu implementation of std::array::operator[].

hardened compiler option is a more recent fortification in newer versions of GNU and CLANG platforms' debug mode compilation. The default in debug mode is the f switch(-fhardened), and defines _GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS along with some more hardening options in debug builds. Disabling it with fno- switch (-fno-hardened), eventually suppresses the macro too.


Disabling the hardening options eventually removes the bounds-checking logic from operator[] invocations and optimizes the exra dependency out, resulting in binary size shrinking. For further reading explor the GNU gcc docs, or search the keywords mentioned in this response.

This is a good answer and helps me solve the problem of code size blowing up, but I’m still curious as to why exception related code is present in the objdump when all these are supposed to be are assertion checks

@jon because assertion is essentially an exception thrown at debug time. The exception maybe modern C++ exception or old structured exception. Either way when exceptions is turned off or function is marked asnoexcept the std::terminate or similar panic mechanism is triggered and exception can't be catched or resolved at runtime.

Is there any reason that irq_callback_table needs to be an std::array<>?  If it were an old fashioned C style array, there would be no bounds checking whatsoever so no possibility of an exception.

For better or worse, I’m trying to follow modern, idiomatic C++ practices which encourages std::array<> over plain C arrays for arrays of known length. So there’s no strong technical reason.

@Jon the reason in this case for preferring std::array over an old fashioned array is for the extra safety it can provide, but it's that safety that's tripping you up.  There are exceptions to every rule (pardon the pun) and it's critical in C++ to know how to evaluate any given situation.

Sure, but I think one can only make that trade off if they fully understand what the consequences are. I didn’t know I was in for 22.5x code size increase from non-obvious implicit behavior. It gives those who discourage C++ for embedded software some justification.
